# why I keep getting "Process finished with exit code 11"?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, clion

I'm new to dynamic memory, I'm trying to learn.
I keep getting in my codes "Process finished with exit code 11".
this is one code:

```
int main()
{
    int *p;
    printf("%d",&p);

    p  = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("failed");
        free(p);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%d",p);
    *p = 4;
    printf("%d",*p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't cast the results of `malloc`, and you should definitely not cast it to a non-pointer type.

Comment: You aren't printing your pointer values safely.  You need to use `%p`, and cast them to `void *`.  And your cast of the `malloc` result is incorrect.  It should be `int *`, not `int` (or you can omit it entirely).  The way it is now, your compiler must have complained.  Why would you ignore such a serious warning?  This is probably the cause of your bug.  Casting a pointer to an int and then (implicitly) back again will not preserve the value if an int is smaller than a pointer.

Comment: If you have a 32-bit `int` and a 64-bit pointer, then you lose 32 of its bits by casting it to `int`. Then when you dereference that corrupted pointer: the cow jumps over the moon.

Comment: When `malloc` returns `NULL`, you are still calling `free(p);`, i.e. `free(NULL);`  Why?  It makes no sense.

Comment: Signal 11 is SIGSEGV. `valgrind` is great at tracing these down. That said, you should ALWAYS enable and heed your compiler's warnings. (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`,) It identifies your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
p  = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

This is not right.  `malloc` returns a pointer (`void *`) and `p` is a pointer; there is no need to cast at all, and certainly not to `int`.    If you are very lucky, the cast to `int` may simply have no effect.  If you are unlucky, such as on machines where pointers are 64 bits and `int` is 32 bits, you'll end up with an incorrect pointer, or some other form of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

A couple other bugs:

- You should use the `%p` format specifier to print pointers, not `%d`.  And you probably want to include spaces or newlines after the values you print, otherwise they'll all run together and be hard to read.
- It's good that you check whether `malloc` succeeded or failed, but if it failed, there is no point in calling `free` on the null pointer that was returned.  `free(NULL)` is defined as doing nothing.

Here's a corrected version of your program ([try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/2FyGZe)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    printf("%p\n",&p);

    p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%p\n",p);
    *p = 4;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    return 0;
}
```